# selenium xpath how can I locate "704 Valita St, "?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

[![I use "find_element_by_xpath('//header/h1/") but result is "704 Valita St,
Venice, CA 90291"][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Db7z.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Db7z.jpg)

url is [here](https://www.zillow.com/homes/recently_sold/Los-Angeles-CA-90291/house,condo,apartment_duplex,townhouse_type/20453731_zpid/96127_rid/12m_days/globalrelevanceex_sort/34.002866,-118.437896,33.983225,-118.492827_rect/13_zm/)

Comment: Please edit your question, attach your image and post the question well formatted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this into a variable:

```
find_element_by_xpath(".//header/h1").getText().split(",")
```

And after get the first element, because the getText option receive the span text too. Something like this "704 Valita St, \nVenice, CA 90291"

Comment: I want only "704 Valita St, " how can I do that ?

Comment: On my answer I split the text by "," character. That returns a list, and the first element is what you need. If you need the "," character too, add to the end.

Comment: there is error: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'@j.barrio

Comment: Right, because I suppose you are using Python and the call is .text :) My getText() function works in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This script only retrieves `"704 Valita St, "`.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.zillow.com/homes/recently_sold/Los-Angeles-CA-90291/house,condo,apartment_duplex,townhouse_type/20453731_zpid/96127_rid/12m_days/globalrelevanceex_sort/34.025454,-118.437896,33.960554,-118.492913_rect/13_zm/")
address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[text()="704 Valita St, "]').text
if ',' in address:
    print(str(address).split(',')[0])
else:
    print(address)
```

Output:

```
704 Valita St
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[starts-with(@id, 'yui_') and @class='notranslate' and not(@class='zsg-h2 addr_city')]").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```